# Run cronjobs as root while Apache is running as a non-root user

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, root

im building a simple Web Application which runs on a tiny device (Odroid C1 with Ubuntu Server 14.04).. the web application will use php.. my problem is that i want to create a "Settings" page where the user can customize, for example, local ip address or reboot/shutdown the machine .. basically i will need to run commands which need root user in general. But, for security reasons i want to deny root access to device to everyone.. moreover, i want to run Apache (and another C++ program which the Web Application interact with) as normal (non-root) user.

i will give you an example to explain better.. in the example "user" will be the non-root user and "root" will be....imagine :)
Hence, i was wondering if this scenario is possible and, if yes, how:

- install apache2 and php;
- create the non-root user "user" and install/run the C++ application in /home/user/prod
- run apache as non-root user (is it possible? how? is it not recommended?)
- create cronjobs to run **as root**.. i will need them to allow web application do root stuffs

I am quite new in web development and system administration, so i have some more questions (most of them may be even noob questions, i am sorry):

- when a customer will boot up the device (which will have no GUI, the only way to interact will be the Web Server, like a router/modem), I know i can run whichever script/command at boot, but what about the user? i mean, since i want to run Apache and the C++ program as non-root.. is there a way to run them at boot as non-root? How?
- is there a way to delete/deny any login? i want the user just push the "Boot" button and connect through his Browser to Apache.. nothing more

Thanks a lot.

EDIT:

- do cronjobs run always as root, which ever user is logged in and whichever program is running? i've never used cronjobs before

Comment: Apache already runs as a non-root user called `www-data`. It is the recommended way to use it.

Comment: ok maybe i wasnt clear.. my problem is that i have to interact with a c++ application which runs in /home/user/prod.. i have to have access to /home/user/prod through php, but, as far as i know, it is not possible get access to files outside the /var/www/ folder ... so, i was wondering if there is a way to run apache with /home/user as working directory.. thanks

Comment: Sure, access to files outside `/var/www` via a URL might not be permitted, but you can use PHP code to access files anywhere in the system that the `www-data` user can access.

Comment: ok i see your suggestion.. basically you are saying to set www-data user as owner of the directory i need to interact with.. right?

Comment: That is the simplest solution, but it may not be necessary. (If the file has read and execute permission for others, you might not need to do anything special.) Cronjobs run as the user who's crontab you edited (or the user specified in `/etc/crontab` for that job).

Comment: ok thanks.. i take advantage of your kindness :) could you take a look at my edit above? thanks a lot again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is possible to grant only some root actions to users?

Yes with `visudo`, or file events, or with the s bit on a script, or withe root `crontab`.

how to run apache etc as non-root user?

That is default for Apache and you can use `su`, `sudo`, or `runuser` for apps that don't already do this.

How to create root cronjobs?

Every user has a crontab, just put your script in root's

how to run services at boot as non-root?

You can use any command in an init script so the answer is the same as your how to run as root question.

is there a way to delete/deny any login?

You can make login require the use of another computer, but no.

i want the user just push the "Boot" button and connect through his Browser to Apache.

That will work by default

do cronjobs run always as root, which ever user is logged in and whichever program is running?

No there is a `crontab` per user, read `man crontab` for details

Comment: thanks for your clarifications.. it's now a little more clear (english is not my first language, i read so much stuffs on CronJobs but without hitting some points)..with your schematic clarifications im now ready to study in a better way.. thanks

Comment: @Sciakysystem Please vote up, mark as answer, or let us know what part of your question is unanswered.

Comment: sorry, voted up right now!